# Naming Docker Containers on start ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

Is there a way to name containers when they start through ECS? Wondering because I'm currently using Datadog to monitor the system usage and the containers are named something long etc like

ecs-datadog-agent-task-1-datadog-agent-c0a1f3e8d9e58dd5e901

would like to set my own name

Comment: AFAIK datadog sees the `hostname` of the container, and not the container name. Are you sure that datadog is reporting what you've posted? FYI the hostname can be configured from ECS to each container.

Comment: oh so the hostname is the same thing as "docker run --name=container_name" ?

Comment: No, they are different things. Hostname is controlled by `docker run --hostname you-host-name`, and in ECS from the container properties in the task definition

Comment: got it thanks for the info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not set a name on the instances of docker that manages amazon. The namespaces it uses are to be able to handle the scaling of the service. Think that if you write the name and then the service you ask for more than one instance of your application, amazon could not instantiate it on the same node.

I hope the explanation has served.

Answer (score 7):

No, there is not a way to control the name used for the container in Amazon ECS.  ECS picks a random name designed to avoid conflicts (since names must be unique in Docker; you can't have two containers with the same name) and you can see the code [here](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/blob/v1.14.3/agent/engine/docker_task_engine.go#L581-L590).

However, ECS does give you a few things that might be able to help you.  There are automatically-assigned Docker labels for the task ARN, the container name in your task definition, the task definition family, the task definition revision, and the cluster; see [here](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/blob/v1.14.3/agent/engine/docker_task_engine.go#L575-L579).  Additionally, you can assign your own custom Docker labels through the task definition.